# RS-232-to-USB is not working

Tags: 13.10, usb, lenovo, tty, serial-port

I have a Konig RS-232 serial-to-USB adapter (no [FTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) chip), but when I try to connect to a Cisco switch/router (via [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), screen, [Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom)...), sometimes it just shows nothing (but it is connected because when I remove the USB it says disconnected, and sometimes it shows garbage.

But it also can just work OK, for about 5-10 seconds, and after that it just freezes.

I checked the adapter on another Linux PC ([Slackware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slackware)), and here it just works flawless.
I'm running [Ubuntu 13.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29) (Saucy Salamander, 3-11-0-15-generic, Lenovo laptop)

[lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb) output

```
remy@remy-laptop-ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 032: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg | grep 2303

```
[22933.099512] pl2303 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[22934.926969] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[22934.927665] pl2303 1-1.2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[22934.929688] usb 1-1.2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I borrowed another converter from a friend (this one does have an FTDI chip), but it still doesn't work. I tried it on USB 2.0 as well as 3.0.